# Web Crawling/Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to learn how to web crawl/web scrape and need some help. I am currently in the process of web scraping from the following website: http://books.toscrape.com/. I am, however, having difficulty web scraping the price, rating, and cover url on this website. Can someone help me? Listed below is the coding that I attempted to use.

for review in data.xpath("//article[@class='product_pod']"):

```
title = i.xpath("h3/a/@title")
price = i.xpath("//p[@class='price_color']/text()")
rating= i.xpath("//p[@class='star-rating']/@class")
coverurl= i.xpath("a/img/@src")
moreinfo= i.xpath("h3/a/@href")
print(title,price,rating,coverurl, moreinfo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://books.toscrape.com/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
product_name = tree.xpath('//article[@class="product_pod"]/h3/a/text()')
product_price=tree.xpath('//div[@class="product_price"]/p/text()[1]')
cover_image=tree.xpath('//div[@class="image_container"]/a/img/@src')
rating=tree.xpath('//article[@class="product_pod"]/p/@class')

def Remove(duplicate): 
    final_list = [] 
    for num in duplicate: 
        if num not in final_list: 
            final_list.append(num) 
    return final_list
product_price=Remove(product_price)
del product_price[1]

final=zip(product_name, product_price,cover_image,rating)
for i in final:
    print(i)

o/p:

('A Light in the ...', '£51.77', 'media/cache/2c/da/2cdad67c44b002e7ead0cc35693c0e8b.jpg', 'star-rating Three')
('Tipping the Velvet', '£53.74', 'media/cache/26/0c/260c6ae16bce31c8f8c95daddd9f4a1c.jpg', 'star-rating One')
('Soumission', '£50.10', 'media/cache/3e/ef/3eef99c9d9adef34639f510662022830.jpg', 'star-rating One')
('Sharp Objects', '£47.82', 'media/cache/32/51/3251cf3a3412f53f339e42cac2134093.jpg', 'star-rating Four')
('Sapiens: A Brief History ...', '£54.23', 'media/cache/be/a5/bea5697f2534a2f86a3ef27b5a8c12a6.jpg', 'star-rating Five')
('The Requiem Red', '£22.65', 'media/cache/68/33/68339b4c9bc034267e1da611ab3b34f8.jpg', 'star-rating One')
('The Dirty Little Secrets ...', '£33.34', 'media/cache/92/27/92274a95b7c251fea59a2b8a78275ab4.jpg', 'star-rating Four')
('The Coming Woman: A ...', '£17.93', 'media/cache/3d/54/3d54940e57e662c4dd1f3ff00c78cc64.jpg', 'star-rating Three')
('The Boys in the ...', '£22.60', 'media/cache/66/88/66883b91f6804b2323c8369331cb7dd1.jpg', 'star-rating Four')
('The Black Maria', '£52.15', 'media/cache/58/46/5846057e28022268153beff6d352b06c.jpg', 'star-rating One')
('Starving Hearts (Triangular Trade ...', '£13.99', 'media/cache/be/f4/bef44da28c98f905a3ebec0b87be8530.jpg', 'star-rating Two')
("Shakespeare's Sonnets", '£20.66', 'media/cache/10/48/1048f63d3b5061cd2f424d20b3f9b666.jpg', 'star-rating Four')
('Set Me Free', '£17.46', 'media/cache/5b/88/5b88c52633f53cacf162c15f4f823153.jpg', 'star-rating Five')
("Scott Pilgrim's Precious Little ...", '£52.29', 'media/cache/94/b1/94b1b8b244bce9677c2f29ccc890d4d2.jpg', 'star-rating Five')
('Rip it Up and ...', '£35.02', 'media/cache/81/c4/81c4a973364e17d01f217e1188253d5e.jpg', 'star-rating Five')
('Our Band Could Be ...', '£57.25', 'media/cache/54/60/54607fe8945897cdcced0044103b10b6.jpg', 'star-rating Three')
('Olio', '£23.88', 'media/cache/55/33/553310a7162dfbc2c6d19a84da0df9e1.jpg', 'star-rating One')
('Mesaerion: The Best Science ...', '£37.59', 'media/cache/09/a3/09a3aef48557576e1a85ba7efea8ecb7.jpg', 'star-rating One')
('Libertarianism for Beginners', '£51.33', 'media/cache/0b/bc/0bbcd0a6f4bcd81ccb1049a52736406e.jpg', 'star-rating Two')
("It's Only the Himalayas", '£45.17', 'media/cache/27/a5/27a53d0bb95bdd88288eaf66c9230d7e.jpg', 'star-rating Two')

#new addition
list(map(list, zip([[el] for el in product_name], [[el] for el in product_price],[[el] for el in cover_image],[[el] for el in rating])))

o/p:
[[['A Light in the ...'],
  ['£51.77'],
  ['media/cache/2c/da/2cdad67c44b002e7ead0cc35693c0e8b.jpg'],
  ['star-rating Three']],
 [['Tipping the Velvet'],
  ['£53.74'],
  ['media/cache/26/0c/260c6ae16bce31c8f8c95daddd9f4a1c.jpg'],
  ['star-rating One']],
 [['Soumission'],
  ['£50.10'],
  ['media/cache/3e/ef/3eef99c9d9adef34639f510662022830.jpg'],
  ['star-rating One']],...]
```

Comment: It worked, but I am trying to have a bracket with all of the information for just a single book. For example, I am trying to have one bracket contain information strictly on the A Light In The Attic book.

Comment: I am so sorry, but do you know how to put the information in single brackets for each book? For example, [Soumission], [$50.10], [Star-One Rating], etc. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: give a right mark to the answer, since it will be a reference to others. Thanks

Comment: I think I just gave it a right mark. I am not sure though. I am very new to this website.

Answer (score 0):

First run on terminal:

```bash
mkdir python_scraper
cd python_scraper

pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Then try the following python code:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_to_scrape = "https://books.toscrape.com/"

request_page = urlopen(url_to_scrape)

page_html = request_page.read()

request_page.close()

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")

# get book title

for data in html_soup.select("ol"): 

    for title in data.find_all("a’"):   

        print(title.get_text())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information.